# Matplotlib cyrillic support

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use Cyrillic for `matplotlib` labels so I found [these](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/whitehorn/rus_matplotlib/blob/master/M1%20Matplotlib%20cyrillic%20russian%20labels.ipynb) examples showing that it can be achieved by:

```
matplotlib.rcdefaults()
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'fantasy'
matplotlib.rcParams['font.fantasy'] = 'Times New Roman', 'Ubuntu','Arial','Tahoma','Calibri'
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1279: UserWarning: findfont: Font family [u'fantasy'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

I'm using `matplotlib` with `prettyplotlib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matpltlib is not able to find the fonts, may be they are in the wrong format or not available under the `matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/` folder. Try converting to `.ttf` and use this code to debug:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

path = '/home/username/fantasy.ttf'
prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path)
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = prop.get_name()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Test text', fontproperties=prop, size=40)
```

You can also see al fonts available to you:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
print matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None)
```

Comment: I'll give it a try but isn't 'fantasy' only the name of the font family under which are all other fonts like 'Times New Roman', 'Ubuntu','Arial','Tahoma','Calibri'.